# Is embedded id the right way to move to mongo from jpa

Tags: java, mongodb, jpa

We have a number of object that have an id of type Long and are stored in MySql and use JPA/Hibernate for ORM. We are going to move some to Mongo in the future. Is it sensible to create an embeddable class for the Id field, e.g. ContentId and use this throughout the system in place of Long so that when we move to MongoDB or anothe noSql database without Long ids that we only have to change the internal representation of the ContentId class. I can only find references to using @EmbeddedId for composite keys. Is this a sensible thing to do? I don't want to have to go through all the code in a year or so when we change and replace Long with ObjectId.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB uses a generated OID as the default Id.  You can also define your own using the _id attribute.  The OID is basically a UUID, which maps best to a String.  I would just use a UUID in MySQL, so you can use the same model on either.  MongoDB does not support a composite id, so using a composite id is probably not a good idea.

EclipseLink supports JPA on both MySQL and MongoDB.  EclipseLink also supports a @UuidGenerator that works with any database.

http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2012/04/eclipselink-jpa-supports-mongodb.html

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/NoSQL

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what EmbeddedId would give you to gain portability .... best to focus on the value generators available and what the datastore would support, and look for how you can have something mappable on both datastores to ease the migration.

[DataNucleus JPA](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1) obviously supports persistence to MongoDB and has for some time, allowing the full range of identities, whether it is the native MongoDB UUID ("identity" in JPA parlance), String-based (uuid, uuid-hex) or numeric ("table"). This gives portability and you can choose what suits your model best. It also supports persistence to many other types of datastores (RDBMS, Excel, ODF, ODBMS, HBase, AppEngine, LDAP, and others) should you need portability to other datastores too.